# Using the official php docker image and running memcached on start

Tags: php, docker, debian, memcached, boot

I have a docker file that I am basing from the php:5.5.36-apache image, for creating image expressly for development. My Dockerfile installs memcached but I am having no luck getting memcached to start on boot. If I ssh into the container and start memcached manually, it starts just fine.

```
FROM php:5.5.36-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    default-jdk 
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends autoconf    
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python python-pip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev \
    apt-utils re2c g++ memcached \
    zlib1g zlib1g-dbg zlib1g-dev zlibc mysql-client php5-mysql \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached\
    && pecl install memcache \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get install -y gettext

RUN pip install hgapi

RUN a2enmod headers \
    && a2enmod rewrite

COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN mkdir /var/www/content

EXPOSE 11211

RUN systemctl enable memcached.service
```

The base image is based on debian:jessie

Comment: You misuse RUN. RUN helps you install and configure the software you need, ADD/COPY adds files, ENV defines your environment variables, and CMD and ENTRYPOINT start your stuff, so they start mysqld in a Mysql docker image, apache in an Apache docker image and so. I do not see CMD or ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile. Checks the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint

Comment: the image that I start from has a CMD that starts apache, which was really the part that was confusing me. See my answer below, I am better now.

Answer (score 3):

This link worked for me for the same issue with php5, apache2 and memcached in a Dockerfile based on ubuntu:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5137

Install supervisor

```
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
```

and config that in Dockerfile:

```
RUN touch  /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf && \
    echo "[supervisord]" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf && \
    echo "nodaemon=true" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN touch /etc/supervisor/conf.d/memcached.conf && \
    echo "[program:memcache]" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/memcached.conf && \
    echo "command=/usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1 -DFOREGROUND" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/memcached.conf && \
    echo "autostart=true" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/memcached.conf && \
    echo "autorestart=true" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/memcached.conf

RUN touch /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache2.conf && \
    echo "[program:apache2]" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache2.conf && \
    echo 'command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"' >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache2.conf && \
    echo "autostart=true" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache2.conf && \
    echo "autorestart=true" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache2.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

This link also explains how to run multiple services in a container:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 1):

php:5.5.36-apache has a bash script called apache2-foreground which uses `exec` to launch apache, that script is called with `CMD ["apache2-foreground"]` at the end of the Dockerfile. This is the one script that will be executed by Docker on start and the `exec` command passes execution off to the system.

My solution which my very well be inelegant and I would not suggest doing this with any kind of production server is to copy the `apache2-foreground` script and start memcached before apache is started. Since this is an image to use as a local development server this meets my needs.

The updated `apache2-foreground`:
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e

```
# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

/etc/init.d/memcached start
exec apache2 -DFOREGROUND
```

Then I replaced:

```
RUN systemctl enable memcached.service
```

with:

```
COPY apache2-foreground /usr/local/bin/
```